# Azure: Give a "WebSite" (not a vm) a public IP

Tags: azure, website

Is there an easy way to give an azure "Website" (not a virtual machine) an IP, so that any time the website makes a connection to an external service, it comes from the same IP.

I really don't know much about Azure, we are just using it to host an exchange adapter (a place that our python app can connect and interact with EWS).

I'd like to give our already existing Website a public IP, but without changing the current domain name (sill using [websitename].azurewebsites.net).

Can this be done?

Comment: `Is there an easy way to give an azure "Website" (not a virtual machine) an IP` - I don't see how. How would web traffic get to the web site if the underlying host doesn't also have that ip address? How would traffic get to the web site? The answer is it wouldn't. `I'd like to give our already existing Website a public IP, but without changing the current domain name` - Why would you need to change the domain name? Your DNS records can "point" to any ip address.

Comment: @joeqwerty In the "Virtual Machines" section of our azure portal, nothing is listed.  So if the website has an underlying VM that I just can't see, I'm fine to change that IP address.

Comment: In order for traffic to get to a web site it has to first get to the host that the web site is running on. If the host doesn't have that ip address then I don't see how traffic can get to a web site on that host with that ip address.

Comment: I don't really care what IP address people use to get to our azure site.  I'm more concerned with the IP address used for outgoing connections.  I want that to be one IP, not a range.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple approaches come to mind:

1. Run your website in a VM with a certain public IP address. This way you are guaranteed to be sending outbound requests from that IP.
2. Configure your website software to use a proxy server. This way your IP address will always be that of your proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Requests made from Azure Websites will always be from the Outbound IP addresses specified for your site. You can find them in Settings/Properties tab of the WebApp in the preview portal.

Another way to find the outbound IP addresses would be to use this site: https://resources.azure.com and go to the subscriptions/resourceGroups/Microsoft.Web/sites tab. There you will find outbound IP addresses and much more in JSON.

Then in the service you can whitelist those IP-s.